# Docker, get root access in dockerfile in order to install packages in a jenkins build image

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, root

I'm trying to build a Jenkins docker image, and I need to install make into it from the image itself and not after running it in a container.

Is there any way to give root access to a Dockerfile ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i got the solution, by adding :

```
USER root
```

you can use any command as root user.